# Executing mail command from inside a function causes a "fork bomb"

Tags: bash, shell-script, mail-command

When I try to execute `mail` from inside a function in a bash script it creates something similar to a fork bomb. To clarify, this creates the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

mail() {
    echo "Free of oxens" | mail -s "Do you want to play chicken with the void?" "example@example.org"
}

mail

exit 0
```

Sometimes you can just kill the command and it'll kill the child processes, but sometimes you'll have to `killall -9`.

It doesn't care whether the mail were sent or not. The *fork bomb* is created either way. And it doesn't seem as adding any check for the exit code, such as `if ! [ "$?" = 0 ]`, helps.

But the script below works as intended, either it outputs an error or it sends the mail.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Free of oxens" | mail -s "Do you want to play chicken with the void?" "example@example.org"

exit 0
```

---

Why does this happen? And how would you go about checking the exit code of the mail command?

Comment: It is called recursion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're invoking the *function* `mail` from within the same function:

```
#!/bin/bash

mail() {
    # This actually calls the "mail" function
    # and not the "mail" executable
    echo "Free of oxens" | mail -s "Do you want to play chicken with the void?" "example@example.org"
}


mail

exit 0
```

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

mailfunc() {
    echo "Free of oxens" | mail -s "Do you want to play chicken with the void?" "example@example.org"
}

mailfunc

exit 0
```

Note that function name is no longer invoked from within the function itself.

Comment: Happens to the best of us, man.

Answer (score 15):

Otherwise:

```
mail(){

    echo olly olly oxenfree | command mail -s 'and the rest' and@more
}
```

...should work fine.

Comment: Perhaps emphasising the `command` part, as for the layperson it is hard to notice that change along with the `olly olly oxenfree` and `'and the rest' and@more` changes, especially with the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - I support this comment.

Comment: It *is* funny though...

Answer (score 3):

The most "traditional" solution in these cases is actually to call the command with full path:

```
mail() {
    echo "Free of oxens" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Do you want to play chicken with the void?" "example@example.org"
}
```

All other answers work, and are probably more portable, but I think that this is the most likely solution you'd find in scripts in the wild real world, so I'm including it for completeness.

Comment: Indeed I'm not used to mail being in /usr/bin.

Comment: @Joshua, it seems to be there on OS X.  In CentOS 6 it's `/bin/mail`.  I think this proves the value of the `command mail` syntax.

Comment: Arch Linux also has this in `/usr` because their paradigm is to move all the binaries to the same directory, so `/bin` is just a symlink to `/usr/bin`. So yes... this isn't portable, but it's more commonly seen than `command`, somehow - especially in legacy boot scripts that were made specifically to each distribution, all the absolute paths were hardcoded (rc scripts in Slackware, for instance).